# Generating WMS service from file geodatabase and layer files using no ArcGIS software?

Tags: wms, file-geodatabase, layer-file

I'm just starting with GIS.

I'm using Leaflet to get a [WMS layer](http://idesc.cali.gov.co:8081/geoserver/wms?SERVICE=WMS). It works fine, but I want to know how can I serve the tiles from my own server. I have a `.gdb` file and several `.lyr` files.

What I want to achieve is generate an endpoint in my server like `wms.example.com` where I can get the WMS layer without consulting an external URL.

Comment: Do you have access to ArcGIS for Desktop and ArcGIS for Server?

Comment: @PolyGeo no, only the files that I downloaded with the information

Comment: With Geoserver http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/reference.html

Comment: You do not need ArcGIS to read a file geodatabase (gdb) or to serve a WMS from it but my understanding is that there is nothing else that can read a layer file (lyr).

Comment: What is a lyr file? Is a generated file from ArcGIS?

Comment: Yes - search on "ArcGIS layer file".

Comment: Can ArcGIS export the lyr styles as SLD?

Comment: @user30184 that's a different question - and one I cannot remember the answer to without checking - but this asker has no ArcGIS software nor mentioned any access to any so it would not help.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you relax your requirement to use layer files and style your layers using another method, I am not aware of a solution that meets all your requirements.

You do not need ArcGIS to read a file geodatabase (gdb) or to serve a WMS from it but my understanding is that there is nothing else that can read a layer file (lyr).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is possible to read a gdb with geoserver?

Comment: @IAmJulianAcosta That's another question.  I suspect the answer can be easily found using a search here or using your favourite search engine, but if not, then ask a new question.